# Foreach loop to move specific files into designated folders

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am learning PowerShell and I am having difficulties with my homework. My goal is to get a listing of all files in current directory, save it to a variable. Then use a foreach loop to move each file to different folders based on the file name, using file tags to search for the file names.

Files:

- 1LectureFile
- 1LabFile
- 1AssignmentFile
- 1.ps1

Folders:

- Lecture
- Lab
- Assignment
- Scripts

The files go into their respective folders when I run the script.

I have to use file tags (such as `*lec*`, `*lab*`, `*Assign*`, `*Scripts*`) to search for the files.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
# Gets a list of all file names and saves it to a variable
$Files2 = Get-ChildItem "dir" -File

foreach ($i in $Files2) {
    #My attempt at searching for the files containing lec
    if (gci ($i -eq "*lec*")) {
        #Moves the file that fits the description into Lecture folder
        Move-Item $i -Destination "Lecture"
    # If $i doesn't fit first if, repeats and looks for Lab
    } elseif ("  ") {
        Move-Item "    "
    }
}
```

I am not expecting anyone to give me the answer. Any tips, or hints or a general guide pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I've searched online but most suggested answers are too difficult for me to comprehend (most commands I have not learned yet).

Comment: How is your code falling short of your goal? What is it not doing? I'm guessing the `-eq` isn't working as expected. Check out [about_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators), particularly `-like`.

Comment: Also, try running a few lines in the console. `$Files2 | Get-Member` is a useful one to find out what the members (properties, methods etc) of the `$Files2` object are. ([Get-Member docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6))

Comment: @gms0ulman I believe I am not understanding how to properly format the if statement to search for all files containing the file tag `*lec*` in order to properly sort the files into the folders.

Comment: at the top of the loop add:  $filename = $i.name this will give you the filename, then instead of if (gci ( $i -eq "") use if ($filename -like "*lec*") you are using -eq against an object, you need to use -like against a string

Comment: as @gms0ulman said, look through get-member and have a look at the contents of $files2.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, I believe I found the reason why I'm stuck.

Comment: Just FYI, with my experience, the best way to learn PowerShell is by using Get-Help -full [command] and Get-Member.

Comment: What do you expect `gci ($i -eq "*lec*")` to do? Are you trying to do a wildcard match? You may want to look into the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-3.0) statement for that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yes, I am trying to do a wildcard match. My goal was to look for files with files containing the words `lec` in them. I'm still in the process of completing the script, but I will report back with a finished result when I am done. For now, `if ($i -like "*filetag")` works like a charm for me and is moving test files into their respective folders the way I want it. I've thought about the `switch` statement as well, I will try it with that afterwards as well.

Comment: One perk of `switch` is that it will iterate for you, so you can just `Switch -wildcard ($files2){` and get rid of the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician isn’t it correct to assume that you need a `foreach` loop to go through all arguments in `$i` even if you’re using a `switch`? Or will the `switch` go through it regardless without the loop?

Comment: The `switch` command will iterate items in an array, just like a `foreach` loop will. If all you have in the `ForEach` loop is your switch, then you do not need the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses :) I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `switch` can be simplified to:

```
switch -Wildcard ($Files2) {
    "*lec*" {Move-Item $_ -Destination "Lecture"}
    "*lab*" {Move-Item $_ -Destination "Lab"}
    "*assign*" {Move-Item $_ -Destination "Assignment"}
    "*.ps1*" {Move-Item $_ -Destination "Scripts"}
}
```

The switch command will iterate through the array of file objects. Within the switch we refer to `$_` which represents the current item of the array that is being tested.

Another way that this could be done is by using a hashtable to create a dictionary mapping where each kind of file should go, then using `-match` in a select statement, and the automatic `$matches` variable to lookup where each file should go in the hashtable. Something like:

```
$PathLookup = @{
        'lec' = "Lecture"
        'lab' = "Lab"
        'assign' = "Assignment"
        '.ps1' = "Scripts"
}

$Files2 | Where{$_.Name -match '(lec|lab|assign|\.ps1)'} | ForEach{
    Move-Item $_ -Destination $PathLookup[$Matches[1]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the helpful hints and tips. I've successfully finished the script and it is working as intended. Instead of using an `if` statement, I used a `Switch` statement instead for more efficiency. Because I am adding more into the loop, the `forloop` is staying or else I would have omitted it.

```
Foreach ($i in $Files2) {

    switch -Wildcard ($i) {
        ("*lec*") {Move-Item $i -Destination "Lecture"}
        ("*lab*") {Move-Item $i -Destination "Lab"}
        ("*assign*") {Move-Item $i -Destination "Assignment"}
        ("*.ps1*") {Move-Item $i -Destination "Scripts"}
    }
}
```